# Algolia retrieve results by multiple facets

Tags: algolia

First of all, I am using Algolia `JavaScript API Client V3 (Deprecated)`

I have the following records

```
{
  category: SEDAN,
  manufacturer: Volkswagen,
  id: '123'
},
{
  category: COUPE,
  manufacturer: Renault,
  id: '234'
},
{
  category: SEDAN,
  manufacturer: Fiat,
  id: '345'
},
{
  category: COUPE,
  manufacturer: Peugeot,
  id: '456'
},
{
  category: SUV,
  manufacturer: Volkswagen,
  id: '567'
}
```

I want to query Algolia and get something similar to the following json

```
{
  categories: {
    SEDAN: {
      count: 2
      items: [{
        Volkswagen: {
          count 1,
          items: [{
            id: '123'
          }]
        }
      },
      {
        Fiat: {
          count 1,
          items: [{
            id: '345'
          }]
        }
      }]

    },
    COUPE: {
      count: 2
      items: [{
        Renault: {
          count 1,
          items: [{
            id: '234'
          }]
        }
      },
      {
        Peugeot: {
          count 1,
          items: [{
            id: '456'
          }]
        }
      }]
    },
    SUV: {
      count: 1,
      items: [{
        Volkswagen: {
          count 1,
          items: [{
            id: '567'
          }]
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I have been trying to query Algolia

```
index
  .search({
    query: '',
    facets: ['category', 'manufacturer'],
    attributesToRetrieve: []
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.facets);
  });
```

But I am not sure if it is possible to combine the facets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`facets` added to a query doesn't work that way. It will simply return the record count for each facet value, not the actual records (https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facets/)

You can create filters around facets and use those to display results by facet value, but there isn't a way to build a single response JSON that is already grouped by facets like you show above. https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/filters/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Chuck_Meyer I was able to do a workaround. As you wrote I created filters for each category I needed and I query the api using the multiple queries (Search Multiple Indexes). I didn't need to search at multiple indexes, but it worked well for the problem I was trying to solve.